# Get column differences between 2 databases (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got 2 databases *almost* identical to one another. However, it seems that for some tables in the new database, they are missing columns that are in the old database.

What would be the best way to see the differences between columns in tables between 2 databases? Specifically, I need to see what columns AREN'T in the new database that ARE in the old one.

I've tried looking this up but most things I found were either not what I needed or looking at "records".

Comment: which db do you use?

Comment: @METUAN Woops! Forgot to include that, sorry! MS SQL, specifically 13.0.4206.0

Comment: I'm interested in what others do, as for me i go the easy way by exporting the databases structure in SQL files and comparing the two with my favorite code editor.

Comment: Are you looking for a script

Comment: @Coding I don't believe that there are too many differences between the schemas of all the tables, so a script to show me what columns aren't in the new database tables but are in the old one would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query the columns from your db using the sys tables and compare the result sets. This script assumes your old db has all the columns you want.

```
;WITH old_db_columns AS (
SELECT c.object_id, c.column_id, c.name AS column_name, t.name AS table_name
FROM old_db.sys.tables t 
INNER JOIN old_db.sys.columns c 
    ON t.object_id = c.object_id
)
, new_db_columns AS (
    SELECT c.object_id, c.column_id, c.name AS column_name, t.name AS table_name
    FROM new_db.sys.tables t 
    INNER JOIN new_db.sys.columns c 
        ON t.object_id = c.object_id
        )

SELECT * 
FROM old_db_columns o
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
SELECT 1
FROM new_db_columns n
WHERE n.table_name = o.table_name
AND n.column_name= o.column_name)
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You may use SQL Compare and SQL Data Compare, tools by Red Gate, to compare and sync databases schema and data.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the create statement of the tables and you can compare them with using any diff tool.

Comment: There's ~500 tables in both databases, so I'd only want this option as a last resort.

Comment: Actually, You can generate entire database and all database objects easly, but maybe you can find difficult to check differences . https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210552(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Check out that video: [VS Comparision](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Visual-Studio/Launch-2013/VS108)

Visual Studio has built in functionality that you are able to do data compares, schema compares and it will generate the differences for you in a script if you need to recitfy the variances.